# Cannot rebuild .ldf when creating database using .mdf file

Tags: sql-server

I tried to rebuild the database using the follow command:

```
CREATE DATABASE ABC ON (FILENAME = 'C:\ABC.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG
```

Error message:

> File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\ABC_log.ldf" may
>   be incorrect.
>
> The log cannot be rebuilt when the primary file is read-only.
>
> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Could not open new database 'ABC'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

But I cannot rebuild the database. Please help me.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a file issue? That is, does a file by that name already exist in that location? Does the service account have permission to read/write in C:\?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  That is file permission problem.

Thanks.